# What is the wavelength of the entire universe?

Tags: universe, wavefunction, wavelength

In quantum physics, particles are also waves.  Larger particles have shorter wavelengths, and macroscopic objects have extremely short wave lengths so that the wave aspect can be ignored, and classical physics works fine at those levels.  The bigger the object, the shorter the wavelength.

So:  What is the wavelength of the biggest "object" of all:  the universe?  Has this ever been calculated?  Does it have any meaning to talk about wave lengths at those levels?

Comment: The fact that you had to put quotes around object suggests that this question probably doesn't make any sense.  First, the the universe may be unbounded, and second, it probably doesn't make sense to think of the universe as an object at all.

Comment: Even if the universe is finite, it doesn't make sense to talk about its total momentum. There's a good discussion of this in Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler, p. 457.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that in general relativity, and also in quantum physics, it becomes difficult to state many questions about the whole universe in a well-posed way. One can say things like "there is a cosmic expansion" or "there is approximate homogeneity on large scales" and "the curvature on large scales is small" but one cannot say "the velocity with respect to other things is ..." nor can one say "the total mass is ..." so it becomes impossible to ascribe a de Broglie wavelength.

The problem with making a statement about velocity is that there is no well-defined way to say with respect to what the velocity is being stated.

The problem with mass is more subtle; it is because in general relativity you cannot define the mass of an object unambiguously except from distances far away where its gravitational effect is small. But there is no way you can get to such a perspective for the universe as a whole.

de Broglie wavelength is itself a relative property (for any given object it varies from one inertial reference frame to another).

Finally, and now I am repeating the point made by John Rennie, it is not very insightful to invoke the concept of a de Broglie wavelength of a composite object unless you are thinking about phenomena where the composite object acts as a whole.

Having said all that, the observable universe is a finite sized object and is not thought to be the entire universe, therefore one could in principle state a mass for the observable universe and one might define a mean velocity with respect to other parts of the universe which cannot be seen by us ... but we have no idea what the value of such a velocity might be.

Answer (score 2):

The *wave* description is an approximation to whatever the underlying reality is, and it only applies in some circumstances. I'm sure you heard of wave/particle duality i.e. the fact that objects behave as waves in some circumstances and particles in others. This means that while the wave description can be an excellent description in some circumstances it is a very poor description in others.

In particular once the wavelength approaches the physical size of the object we cannot usefully treat the object as a single wave. Once the wavelength, and hence the resolution, of the wave falls below the size of the object its components will start behaving independantly. So for example, once the de Broglie wavelength of a proton falls below its size we need to treat it as a collection of partons not a single object.

This means you could only assign a wavelength to the universe if its wavelength was (considerably) bigger than the universe, which is obviously impossible.